# group by and order by count desc taking time

Tags: mysql, sql

The query take more than 6 seconds for 4 million records. Any other procedure can be done to minimize the query time.

```
SELECT title_id, count(title_id) as count
FROM `title_keywords`
WHERE keyword_id in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) 
GROUP BY title_id 
ORDER BY count desc
```

Index and unique columns

[image: See the index of table on picture]

Added composite index too[image: added composite index]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `COUNT` function needs to potentially touch every record in each group, there may not be much which can speed up the aggregation.  However, we might be able to take advantage of an index to speed up the `WHERE` clause:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON title_keywords (keyword_id, title_id);
```

You could also try reversing the order of the index columns, and in either case perhaps check the execution plan using `EXPLAIN`.  The reason this index might work is that it would allow MySQL to quickly access on the matching `keyword_id` records.  The index also covers `title_id`, so that this value would be available in the leaf nodes of the B-tree.

Comment: I added the picture of table index, please look at question

Comment: I don't see any two column index being defined there.  The question to ask you now is have you tried the index which I _suggested_ to you in my answer?

Comment: I have index on title_id and keyword_id two columns.

Comment: Did you create the index specifying _two_ columns?  Note that having separate indices on each column is _not_ the same thing...MySQL probably won't be able to use that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192839/discussion-between-muthukrishnan-c-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Comment: Added composite index, but it's taking same time.

Answer (score 0):

try avoid IN clause   using a INNER JOIN

```
SELECT title_id, count(title_id) as count 
FROM title_keywords 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT 1 col1
  UNION 
  SELECT 2
  UNION 
  SELECT 3
  UNION 
  SELECT 4
  UNION 
  SELECT 5
  UNION 
  SELECT 6
  UNION 
  SELECT 7
  UNION 
  SELECT 8
  UNION 
  SELECT 9    
) t t.col1 = title_keywords.keyword_id  

group by title_id 
order by count desc
```

and be sure you have a proper index  on

table   title_keywords columns( keyword_id, title_id )

Comment: This query taking more time than normal where in query

Comment: check  better .. and be sure you have the composite index suggested

Comment: Done, still getting same result.